# Scrapy pipeline run at spider_opened needs value from item

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I have a pipeline that  runs at spider_opened to retrieve a value `lastseen`from mysql, in turn this value is used in later pipelines to test if I need to drop item and/or close spider.  This value must stay constant and can not be updated during the spider session. The question is: since I have mupltiple spiders in project, I'd like to include an item field in this method, is this even possible? I understand that at the time the pipeline runs, spider just opened and no items returned yet, so maybe I need to code differently?

```
 class DuplicatesPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        query = """
                mysql query that has a variable %s
                """

        dbConn = MySQLdb.connect(#settings)
        dictCursor = dbConn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

        dictCursor.execute(query, (item['catid'])) # need supply variable here
        self.lastseen = dictCursor.fetchone()

        dictCursor.close
        dbConn.close()
```